# Handling multiple OpenId login from different OpenId providers for the same user

Tags: openid

Suppose I've an account at [example](http://www.example.com) which I used to login through OpenId, and hence it has only one profile of mine. If I login from another OpenId Provider different from the previous OpenId provider, now will there be a duplicate profile of mine? How does OpenId handles such kind of ambiguity, or is it upto that website of handling such kind of ambiguity?

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Specification doesn't define any mechanism for this scenario. It is totally up to the website developer to handle this.